# Representations of algebraic group and 2-categorical limit of representations of Frobenius kernels

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I was reading the following lecture notes https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.14791 by Ciappara and Williamson and have a question regarding a statement in the notes in section 3.

*Summery of section 3.1 in above:*
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Then we can define a new $k$-algebra $A^{(m)}$ where $\lambda \cdot a = \lambda^{p^{-m}}a$. Then we have the following map of $k$-algebras
$$
  \sigma_A : A \rightarrow A^{(m)} \quad\text{ by } x \mapsto x^{p}
$$
Now let $X$ be a $k$-scheme defined as functor. Then we can get the scheme $X^{(1)}$ via base-change along $\sigma_k : k \rightarrow k^{(1)}$, we call this the *Frobenius twist* of $X$. As functor $X^{(1)}$ is given by $X^{(1)}(A) = X(A^{(-1)})$. We then get the *Frobenius morphism* $\text{Fr}: X \rightarrow X^{(1)}$ by $X(\sigma_A) : X(A) \rightarrow X(A^{(-1)})$. By iterating the construction of $\text{Fr}$ we get a chain of morphism
$$
 X \rightarrow X^{(1)} \rightarrow X^{(2)} \rightarrow ...
$$
We denote the composition $X \rightarrow X^{(n)}$ by $\text{Fr}^n$. Now let $G$ be a $k$-group scheme. Then we can define the $n$*-th Frobenius kernel* of $G$ to be the group scheme $G_n = \text{ker Fr}^{n} \leq G$.

*Question:*
Now on page 11, just after Figure 1, it is stated that "We also have the result that $\text{Rep}(G) \hookrightarrow 2\text{-lim } \text{Rep}(G_n)$; here we refer to a 2-limit of categories, viewing them as objects in some appropriate 2-category".

Does anybody now a reference for this or is this easy to see if one is more familar with 2-limits? We have the restriction functors $\text{Res}_{G_n} : \text{Rep}(G) \rightarrow \text{Rep}(G_n)$ so (if 2-limits work kind of like normal limits?) we should get a map $\text{Rep}(G) \rightarrow 2\text{-lim } \text{Rep}(G_n)$ but how do we show that this is  mono? Btw will the functor we get be a monoidal functor?

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: The 2-category theory is a bit too far behind me to comment on in detail. But the general idea behind why the functor is mono is that if you have two reps that are isomorphic over all Frobenius kernels, then they are isomorphic as $G$-reps.
The intuitive part of this is to start with irreps and note that once the Frobenius kernels gets large enough (relative to the highest weight of the irrep and the base characterictic), the rep stays irreducible over the Frobenius kernel.

Comment: I think the above is spelled out in details in Jantzen's book, though without the language of 2-categories.